# CKeditor textarea data only submit first into database laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, ckeditor

Im having a problem where when I submit the form , my data for ckeditor only insert one line to database . When I try to vardump the variable of data request it show all the data from line 1 to line 3 .

**Data vardump**

[image]

**Data Insert Into Database**

[image]

Here Is my code for store the data into database .

```
    $aktiviti->title = $request->input('aktivitiName');
    $aktiviti->content = $request->input('text');
    $aktiviti->image_url = $url;
    $aktiviti->updated_by = $user_name;
    $result = $aktiviti->save();
```

Here is my ajax to submit the form

```
$('#formaktiviti').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = CKEDITOR.instances['ckeditor'].getData();
        console.log(value);
        var myform = document.getElementById("formaktiviti");
        var fd = new FormData(myform );
        fd.append('text',value);
          $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
          $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8888/KoBPM/public/postAktiviti',
            method: 'POST',
            data:fd,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
           success:function(data){
              var response = JSON.parse(data);
              if(response.status == true){
                alert('success')
                  }else{
                alert('failed');
              }
            }
          });
      });
```

So what cause the data not complete when submit into database ?

Comment: Change your content field to text as it is I think string that why its not saving the whole data.

Answer (score 0):

u var_dump() the data and it seems right, in my first sight, ur database field may be not suitable or long enough , u can use longtext to save the field if it can solve ur problem if not, remove ur Ajax to see the data  u saved. best wishes.

Comment: Yes thank you , just now im view it in Microsoft server database management , and its actually already submitted . Just in Navicat it won't display the next line/new line